# Django "App with label XYZ could not be found"

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I've gone through all of the various questions on this, but none have fixed my problem.  I'm working on a django project with the most up-to-date versions of django, virtualenv, on a Windows 7 home computer with Python 2.7.  The project is meant to be up on Heroku, but it doesn't work locally either.

Basically, when trying to run `manage.py sqlall appname`, it always returns the following error tree:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\commands\test.py", line 49, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\commands\test.py", line 72, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\test\simple.py", line 380, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\test\simple.py", line 263, in build_suite
    app = get_app(label)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\models\loading.py", line 152, in get_app
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("App with label %s could not be found" % app_labe
l)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label tryagain could not b
e found
```

It won't even recognize a brand new, untouched app.  For example, if I run `manage.py startapp tryagain` and then add `'tryagain'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, I still get the same error when trying something like `manage.py test tryagain`.  The only way my `settings.py` file differs from the normal one is that for Heroku, I've added the following two lines:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm driving myself crazy here.

EDIT:

First, I tried starting a brand new Django project with a brand new app, and it still didn't work, even though everything was completely untouched.

Since I can't figure out what settings are relevant, I've provided the entire `settings.py` module below for my troublesome project:

```
# Django settings for <problem> project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

##DATABASES = {
##    'default': {
##        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
##        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
##        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
##        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
##        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
##        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
##    }
##}


# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = ''

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'craigslist.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'kombu.transport.django',
    #'djcelery',
    '<problemappname>',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

BROKER_BACKEND = 'django'

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}


import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}

# note that this becomes the following:
# DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
#                           'NAME': '',
#                           'HOST': 'localhost',
#                           'USER': None,
#                           'PASSWORD': None,
#                           'PORT':  None } }
```

**Additional EDIT:**
Directory structure can be seen below, comments in parentheses.

```
 - craigslist (project)
     - craigslist
         - __init__.py
         - settings.py
         - urls.py
         - wsgi.py
     - venv (virtualenv)
         - Include (directory)
         - Lib (directory)
         - Scripts (directory)
     - webpage (app)
         - __init__.py
         - models.py
         - tests.py
         - views.py
     - __init__.py
     - listings.py (custom module, not touched yet)
     - manage.py
     - requirements.txt
     - settings.py
     - urls.py
```

**third edit:**
Thought it might also be helpful that when I run `manage.py syncdb`, I get the following error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\craigslist\venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly co
nfigured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more
details.
```

**Yet another edit:**
As requested, here is my `models.py`.

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class listing(models.Model):
    body = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    url = models.URLField(primary_key = True)
    scraping_time = models.DateTimeField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    posting_time = models.DateTimeField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    # imglist as separate model

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class imagelist(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(listing)
    img_url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.img_url
```

Comment: please post the relevant settings

Comment: Could you include what all you have checked? For example, have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483636/how-to-test-django-application-placed-in-subfolder

Comment: @phaedrus I could start going through and rechecking, but I've been searching for the answer for two hours now and checked every answer I've seen.  I have looked at that one, didn't help because the main issue was there that the apps were grouped in a directory, and mine aren't, and also mine have `__init__.py` and `models.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much headache, I just figured it out.

For some reason, there are two `settings.py`s--one in the overall project directory `craigslist`, and one in the subdirectory `craigslist\craigslist`, and I was editing the top-level `settings.py`, and I should have been editing the lower one.  I have no idea why this is, but after copying over all the code from the top-level to the sub-level one, suddenly `manage.py sqlall webpage` worked.

Comment: Are you using Django 1.4? The project layout changed in that version. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized that.  Yes, I'm pretty sure that Django 1.4 was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my problem was that I modified my DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, but changed it only in my gunicord settings file (/webapps/run/gunicorn_start).
So the 'python mange.py' was still referring to an old settings.pyc file (the 'py' file was already deleted, but the 'pyc' remained...).

Once I did the following, everything worked:
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=...